# Logging terminal output after running script

Tags: unix, logging, putty

I've just executed a script on a server and forgot to enable the logging of the output.

is it possible to record everything since i started the session after the script has finised executing? (baring in mind this script takes several hours to run)

Comment: can you share the relevant portions of your script. Depending on the set up, the messages might or might not be recoverable

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.